# Show time from microtime in top of page

Tags: php

I am using microtime to get the script execution time

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
....
....
//many process here, many result be printed here
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = substr(($time_end - $time_start),0,5);
echo time;
```

is it possible to print `$time` in above of result page? I've tried using css too, too print it in above, but, `$time` still be printed in the bottom of resul page.

Comment: Move it to the top of the page?

Comment: Don't output anything until all your business logic is completed. Then you can put it wherever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

```
//many process here, many result be printed here
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = substr(($time_end - $time_start),0,5);
?>
<div class="time">
    <?php echo time; ?>
</div>

<style>
.time{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:9999;
}
</style>
```

Did you try just echoing it out into the dom like so?